# cannot estimate gas error when deploying with solidity-create2-deployer

Tags: contract-deployment, error, gas-estimate, create2

I continuously get the `cannot estimate gas` error when attempting to deploy a contract using the solidity-create2-deployer contract and I'm clueless as to where the error arises.

find my code below

```
const creat2 = async () =>{

var daiAddress = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"
const sourceCode = await fetch(`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=${daiAddress}&apikey=${apiKey}`)
const getAbi = await fetch(`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getAbi&address=${daiAddress}&apikey=${apiKey}`)
const jsonAbi = await getAbi?.json()
const abi = await jsonAbi?.result
var abijson = JSON.parse(abi)

console.log(abijson)
const saucy = await sourceCode?.json()

var source = await saucy?.result
var constructr = abijson.filter(object => object.type == "constructor")
var constructor = constructr[0]?.inputs
console.log(constructor)


if(source[0]?.Proxy == "1"){
  var daiAddress = source[0]?.Implementation 
  const sourceCode = await fetch(`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getsourcecode&address=${daiAddress}&apikey=${apiKey}`)
  const saucy = await sourceCode?.json()
  var source = await saucy?.result
  console.log(source[0])
  console.log(source[0]?.ConstructorArguments)

  const getAbi = await fetch(`https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=contract&action=getAbi&address=${daiAddress}&apikey=${apiKey}`)
  const jsonAbi = await getAbi?.json()
  const abi = await jsonAbi?.result
  var abijson = JSON.parse(abi)
  var constructr = abijson.filter(object => object.type == "constructor")
  var constructor = constructr[0]?.inputs
  console.log(constructor)

  // const constructor = ethers.utils.AbiCoder.prototype.decode(source[0]?.ConstructorArguments)
  // console.log(constructor)
  // decode args 
  

}
let constructorTypes = []
for (let i =0; i<constructor.length; i++){
  constructorTypes.push(constructor[i]?.internalType)
}
console.log(constructorTypes)
console.log(source[0]?.ConstructorArguments)

const bytecode = await web3.eth.getCode(daiAddress)
console.log(bytecode)
const salt = generateRandomSalt(); // Choose a salt value

// const constructorTypes = ["uint256"]
const constructorArgue = "0x" + source[0]?.ConstructorArguments
console.log(constructorArgue)
const constructorArgs = (ethers.utils.AbiCoder.prototype.decode(constructorTypes, constructorArgue)).toString()
console.log(constructorArgs)


const signer = new ethers.Wallet(initiatorPK, provider1); // Create a wallet with your private key and provider

const zaiAddress = getCreate2Address({
  salt: salt,
  contractBytecode: bytecode,
  constructorTypes: constructorTypes,
  constructorArgs: [constructorArgs]
});
```

console.log(zaiAddress)

```
const { txHash, address, receipt }  = await deployContract({
  salt: salt,
  contractBytecode: bytecode,
  constructorTypes: constructorTypes,
  constructorArgs: [constructorArgs],
  signer: signer,
}); 

const deployed = await isDeployed(address, provider1);
console.log(deployed)
```

}